# Problema para formular una pregunta sobre cómo crear varios controladores en un proyecto MVC (Java)

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

No sé ni siquiera cómo empezar para hacer esta pregunta, desde mi punto de vista tendría que utilizar mucho código para que alguien reproduzca el problema, pero no se cómo aislar el verdadero problema sin hacer referencia a todo este código completo, quisiera que si pueden me ayudaran para formular la pregunta.

Quizás el título podría ser: **Problema al Crear varios Controladores en un proyecto MVC - Java**

Lo que quiero hacer es crear un **Controlador** para cada **Vista**, pero al crear un segundo controlador este no funciona, no abre la ventana o **JIntenarFrame** que corresponde.

Tengo este código en el controlador de la ventana principal, funciona bien, pues acciona a las órdenes de la **Vista**:

```java
package ControladorProyecto;

import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Admin;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Clientes;
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Proyecto_ControladorAdmin implements ActionListener{

    private Proyecto_Clientes cliente= null;
    private Proyecto_Admin factureAdmin= null;

    private enum Ventana{
        getJMenuClientes,
    }

    public Proyecto_ControladorAdmin(Proyecto_Admin factureAdmin){
        this.factureAdmin= factureAdmin;
    }

    public void abrirFacture(){
        //Inicialización del Frame factureAdmin
        this.factureAdmin.setTitle("FACTURE");
        this.factureAdmin.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.factureAdmin.setVisible(true);

        //Definición de los eventos de los Componentes
        this.factureAdmin.getJMenuClientes().addActionListener(this);
        this.factureAdmin.getJMenuClientes().setActionCommand("getJMenuClientes");
        //this.cc= new ControladorCliente();
    }

    //Centrar los JInternalFrame en el Desktop
    public JInternalFrame centralizarInternalFrame(JInternalFrame InternalFrame) {
        int x = (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getWidth() / 2) - InternalFrame.getWidth() / 2;
        int y = (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getHeight() / 2) - InternalFrame.getHeight() / 2;
        if (InternalFrame.isShowing()) {
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
        } else {
            this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().add(InternalFrame);
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
            InternalFrame.setVisible(true);
            InternalFrame.moveToFront();
        }
        return InternalFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        switch (Ventana.valueOf(ae.getActionCommand())) {

            case getJMenuClientes:
                if (!(this.cliente instanceof Proyecto_Clientes)) {
                    this.cliente = new Proyecto_Clientes();
                    this.cliente.setTitle("CLIENTES");
                    this.centralizarInternalFrame(this.cliente);
                } else if (this.cliente instanceof Proyecto_Clientes) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La ventana ya está abierta");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

El **verdadero problema** está en este código que corresponde al segundo **Controlador**, no acciona a las órdenes de la **Vista** abriendo el **JInternalFrame** que debe:

```java
package ControladorProyecto;

import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Admin;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Clientes;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_NuevoCliente;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Proyecto_ControladorCliente implements ActionListener{

    private Proyecto_Admin factureAdmin= null;
    private Proyecto_Clientes clientes= null;
    private Proyecto_NuevoCliente nuevoCliente= null;


    private enum Componentes{
        txtBuscarCliente,
        tablaClientes,
        getBtnRegistrarCliente
    }

    public Proyecto_ControladorCliente(Proyecto_Clientes clientes){
        this.clientes= clientes;
    }

    public void abrirCliente(){
        this.clientes.getBtnRegistrarCliente().addActionListener(this);
        this.clientes.getBtnRegistrarCliente().setActionCommand("getBtnRegistrarCliente");
    }

    public JInternalFrame centralizarInternalFrame(JInternalFrame InternalFrame) {
        int x= (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getWidth()/2)- InternalFrame.getWidth()/2;
        int y= (this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().getHeight()/2)- InternalFrame.getHeight()/2;
        if(InternalFrame.isShowing()){
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
        }else{
            this.factureAdmin.getDesktop().add(InternalFrame);
            InternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
            InternalFrame.setVisible(true);
            InternalFrame.toFront();
        }       
        return InternalFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        switch (Componentes.valueOf(ae.getActionCommand())) {

            case getBtnRegistrarCliente:
                if (!(this.nuevoCliente instanceof Proyecto_NuevoCliente)) {
                    this.nuevoCliente = new Proyecto_NuevoCliente();
                    this.nuevoCliente.setTitle("NUEVO CLIENTE");
                    this.centralizarInternalFrame(this.nuevoCliente);
                } else if (this.nuevoCliente instanceof Proyecto_NuevoCliente) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La ventana ya está abierta");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el código de la clase inicializadora:

```java
package Proyecto;

import ControladorProyecto.Proyecto_ControladorAdmin;
import ControladorProyecto.Proyecto_ControladorCliente;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Clientes;
import InterfazProyecto.Proyecto_Admin;

public class IncializarProyecto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Proyecto_Admin factAdmin = new Proyecto_Admin();
        Proyecto_Clientes cl = new Proyecto_Clientes();

        new Proyecto_ControladorAdmin(factAdmin).abrirFacture();
        new Proyecto_ControladorCliente(cl).abrirCliente();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 no entiendo que hace esta pregunta en meta.

Comment: @rnd está tratando de obtener ayuda en cómo sintetizar la pregunta para que no sea una pared de código como lo es actualmente. En caso de no poder hacerse, entonces deberíamos indicarle que la publique así en el sitio oficial.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza eso lo entiendo, pero poner la pared de código aquí es igual que ponerla en el sitio principal. Excepto que, se contamina meta.

Comment: Esa es su duda: cómo evitar colocar esa pared de código en el otro lado para que su pregunta sea de calidad.

Comment: @rnd, entiendo y estoy consciente de que es mucho código para una sola inquietud pero no se como resumirla, no se como hacer un modelo simple y claro mas de lo que es, si saben cual es el problema pues díganme que la publique en SOes, si pueden responderla, lo que haré ahora es que quitaré el código para que reproduzcan la demo, de esta manera no será tanto el código.

Comment: @David publícala en el sitio principal tal y como lo hiciste aquí pero sin la explicación de como hacerla más corta.

Comment: Te refieres a todo el código

Comment: Agrego referencia de la pregunta ya formulada: [Problema al ejecutar una clase Controlador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27487/problema-al-ejecutar-una-clase-controlador)